# countif importrange returns 0

Tags: google-sheets, countif, importrange

I have this function:

```
=countif(ImportRange("ifgouhaduoahndaidhnoiadhnoadhoahoda","video_report.csv!F:F"),A2)
```

So what we are looking for is to look for the number of times the specified word is mentioned in the whole of column F from the sheet and after show the number in the cell (A2, in this case) on another sheet. But somehow the code we tried doesn't work. Why? We even tried to replace the cell (A2) to the specified word we are looking for but still it **always returns 0**.

Can someone enlighten us please?

Thank you.

Comment: This might sound very simple, but have you checked if there is values of `A2` in the range? Also it will be very helpful if you share the range and sheet to try to work it as well.

Comment: Yea it has values. Anyways I have solved it already on my own, thank you for the reply.

Comment: Glad to hear that, Could you maybe post your solution as an answered so other people can benefit from it?